# Relationship between Binomial and Beta distributions

Tags: binomial-distribution, beta-binomial-distribution, beta-distribution

I'm more of a programmer than a statistician, so I hope this question isn't too naive.

It happens in sampling program executions at random times. If I take N=10 random-time samples of the program's state, I could see function Foo being executed on, for example, I=3 of those samples. I'm interested in what that tells me about the actual fraction of time F that Foo is in execution.

I understand that I is binomially distributed with mean F*N. I also know that, given I and N, F follows a beta distribution. In fact I've verified by program the relationship between those two distributions, which is

```
cdfBeta(I, N-I+1, F) + cdfBinomial(N, F, I-1) = 1
```

The problem is I don't have an intuitive feel for the relationship. I can't "picture" why it works.

EDIT: All the answers were challenging, especially @whuber's, which I still need to grok, but bringing in order statistics was very helpful. Nevertheless I've realized I should have asked a more basic question: Given I and N, what is the distribution for F? Everyone has pointed out that it's Beta, which I knew. I finally figured out from Wikipedia ([Conjugate prior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior)) that it appears to be `Beta(I+1, N-I+1)`. After exploring it with a program, it appears to be the right answer. So, I would like to know if I'm wrong. And, I'm still confused about the relationship between the two cdfs shown above, why they sum to 1, and if they even have anything to do with what I really wanted to know.

Comment: If "what you actually wanted to know" is "the actual fraction of time that Foo is in execution," then you are asking about a Binomial confidence interval or a (Bayesian) Binomial credible interval.

Comment: @whuber: Well I've used the random-pause method of performance tuning for over 3 decades, and some other people have discovered it too. I've told people that if some condition is true on 2 or more random-time samples, then removing it would save a good fraction of time. HOW good a fraction is what I've tried to be explicit about, assuming we don't know a Bayesian prior. Here's the general flame: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777556/alternatives-to-gprof/1779343#1779343

Comment: Nice idea.  The statistical assumption is that the interruption is independent of the execution state, which is a reasonable hypothesis.  A **binomial confidence interval** is a good tool to use to represent the uncertainty.  (It can be an eye-opener, too: in your 3/10 situation, a symmetric two-sided 95% CI for the true probability is [6.7%, 65.2%].  In a 2/10 situation the interval is [2.5%, 55.6%].  These are wide ranges! Even with 2/3, the lower limit is still less than 10%.  The lesson here is that something fairly rare can happen twice.)

Comment: @whuber: Thanks. You're right. Something more useful is the expected value. As far as priors go, I point out that if you only see something once, it doesn't tell you much *unless* you happen to know the program is in an infinite (or exceedingly long) loop.

Comment: I think all of the answers and comments have certainly been enlightening and correct, but no one really touched on the interesting equality that @MikeDunlavey put in his original post. This equality can be found on the Beta wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function but there is no description given of why that is the case, its just stated as a property.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Consider the order statistics $x_{[0]} \le x_{[1]} \le \cdots \le x_{[n]}$ of $n+1$ independent draws from a uniform distribution.  Because [order statistics have Beta distributions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#The_order_statistics_of_the_uniform_distribution), the chance that $x_{[k]}$ does not exceed $p$ is given by the Beta integral

$$\Pr[x_{[k]} \le p] = \frac{1}{B(k+1, n-k+1)} \int_0^p{x^k(1-x)^{n-k}dx}.$$

(Why is this?  Here is a non-rigorous but memorable demonstration.  The chance that $x_{[k]}$ lies between $p$ and $p + dp$ is the chance that out of $n+1$ uniform values, $k$ of them lie between $0$ and $p$, at least one of them lies between $p$ and $p + dp$, and the remainder lie between $p + dp$ and $1$.  To first order in the infinitesimal $dp$ we only need to consider the case where exactly one value (namely, $x_{[k]}$ itself) lies between $p$ and $p + dp$ and therefore $n - k$ values exceed $p + dp$.  Because all values are independent and uniform, this probability is proportional to $p^k (dp) (1 - p - dp)^{n-k}$.  To first order in $dp$ this equals $p^k(1-p)^{n-k}dp$, precisely the integrand of the Beta distribution.  The term $\frac{1}{B(k+1, n-k+1)}$ can be computed directly from this argument as the multinomial coefficient ${n+1}\choose{k,1, n-k}$ or derived indirectly as the normalizing constant of the integral.)

By definition, the event $x_{[k]} \le p$ is that the $k+1^\text{st}$ value does not exceed $p$.  Equivalently, *at least* $k+1$ of the values do not exceed $p$: this simple (and I hope obvious) assertion provides the intuition you seek. The probability of the equivalent statement is given by the Binomial distribution,

$$\Pr[\text{at least }k+1\text{ of the }x_i \le p] = \sum_{j=k+1}^{n+1}{{n+1}\choose{j}} p^j (1-p)^{n+1-j}.$$

**In summary**, the Beta integral breaks the calculation of an event into a series of calculations: finding at least $k+1$ values in the range $[0, p]$, whose probability we normally would compute with a Binomial cdf, is broken down into mutually exclusive cases where *exactly* $k$ values are in the range $[0, x]$ and 1 value is in the range $[x, x+dx]$ for all possible $x$, $0 \le x \lt p$, and $dx$ is an infinitesimal length.  Summing over all such "windows" $[x, x+dx]$--that is, integrating--must give the same probability as the Binomial cdf.

[image]

Comment: I appreciate the effort. I'm going to have to really study this because it's not my "native tongue". Also, I'm seeing a lot of dollar signs and formatting stuff. Is there something I don't know about that makes it look like real math?

Comment: @Mike See http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/q/218/919 .

Comment: I'm a little slow, but you're getting through to me.
The denominator of the Beta integral is exactly what I came up with.

Comment: It's a little late, but I finally got time to sit down and re-create your argument. The key was "multinomial coefficient". I had tried figuring it out using plain old binomial coefficients and I was getting all balled up. Thanks again for a nice answer.

Answer (score 14):

Look at the pdf of Binomial as a function of $x$:  $$f(x) = {n\choose{x}}p^{x}(1-p)^{n-x}$$ and the pdf of Beta as a function of $p$: $$g(p)=\frac{\Gamma(a+b)}{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)}p^{a-1}(1-p)^{b-1}$$  
You probably can see that with an appropriate (integer) choice for $a$ and $b$ these are the same. As far as I can tell, that's all there is to this relationship: the way $p$ enters into the binomial pdf just happens to be called a Beta distribution.

Comment: I know those look almost the same, but if I substitute y for n-x, and if I take the Beta pdf and substitute x for a-1 and y for b-1 I get an extra factor of (x+y+1), or n+1. i.e. (x+y+1)!/x!/y!*p^x*q^y. That seems to be enough to throw me off.

Comment: Maybe somebody will chime in with a full response, but in an "intuitive" explanation we can always hand-wave away constants (like $n+1$) that do not depend on the variables of interest ($x$ and $p$), but are required to make the pdf add/integrate to 1. Feel free to replace the "equality" signs with "proportional to" signs.

Comment: Good point. I think I'm getting closer to an understanding. I'm still trying to be able to say what x tells you about the p distribution, and why those two cdfs sum to 1.

Comment: I take a different view of "intuitive" explanations.  In some cases we don't care too much about constants, but in this case the *crux* of the matter is to see why an n+1 appears and not an n.  If you don't understand that then your "intuition" is incorrect.

Answer (score 5):

As you noted, the Beta distribution describes the distribution of the trial probability parameter $F$, while the binomial distribution describes the distribution of the outcome parameter $I$. Rewriting your question, what you asked about was why 
$$P(F \le \frac {i+1} n)+P(I \le fn-1)=1$$
$$P(Fn \le i+1)+P(I+1 \le fn)=1$$
$$P(Fn \le i+1)=P(fn<I+1)$$
That is, the likelihood that the observation plus one is greater than the expectation of the observation is the same as the likelihood that the observation plus one is greater than the expectation of the observation.

I admit that this may not help intuit the original formulation of the problem, but maybe it helps to at least see how the two distributions use the same underlying model of repeated Bernoulli trials to describe the behavior of different parameters.

Comment: I appreciate your take on it. All the answers are helping me to think about the question and possibly understand better what I'm asking.

Comment: I revised the question, if you care to take a look. Thanks.

Comment: Regarding your revision: Yes, $F\sim Beta(I+1,N-I+1)$, as long as your sampling intervals are long enough that each observation is independent and identically distributed.

Note that if you want to be Bayesian about it and specify a nonuniform prior distribution for what you expect the actual proportion to be, you can add something else to both parameters.

Comment: @sesqu, could your answer be somehow related to my question here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/147978/probability-distribution-for-a-proportion-based-on-continuous-quantities? I would appreciate your thoughts on it.

Answer (score 5):

**Summary:** It is often said that Beta distribution is a distribution on distributions! But what is means?

It essentially means that you may fix $n,k$ and think of $\mathbb P[Bin(n,p)\geqslant k]$ as a function of $p$. What the calculation below says is that the value of $\mathbb P[Bin(n,p)\geqslant k]$ increases from $0$ to $1$ when you tune $p$ from $0$ to $1$. The increasing rate at each $p$ is exactly $\beta(k,n-k+1)$ at that $p$.

[image]

---

Let $Bin(n,p)$ denote a Binomial random variable with $n$ samples and the probability of success $p$. Using basic algebra we have

$$\frac d{dp}\mathbb P[Bin(n,p)=i]=n\Big(\mathbb P[Bin(n-1,p)=i-1]-\mathbb P[Bin(n-1,p)=i]\Big).$$

*It has also some nice combinatorial proof, think of it as an exercise!*

So, we have:

$$\frac d{dp}\mathbb P[Bin(n,p)\geqslant k]=\frac d{dp}\sum_{i=k}^{n}\mathbb P[Bin(n,p)=i]=n\Big(\sum_{i=k}^{n}\mathbb P[Bin(n-1,p)=i-1]-\mathbb P[Bin(n-1,p)=i]\Big)$$
which is a telescoping series and can be simplified as

$$\frac d{dp}\mathbb P[Bin(n,p)\geqslant k]=n\mathbb P[Bin(n-1,p)=k-1]=\frac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!}p^{k-1}(1-p)^{n-k}=\beta(k,n-k+1).$$

---

**Remark** To see an interactive version of the plot look at [this](https://github.com/bidgoli/Exploratory-Math-Analysis). You may download the notebook or just use the Binder link.

Comment: This probably most directly addresses the aspect of the question regarding CDF's, +1, binder notebook definitely helpful too. It is not clear to me personally though how a differential identity might have a combinatorial interpretation / proof, although maybe it is related to an identity involving conditional probabilities? I don't know  / understand, tbh, in any case the ideas and results in this answer are definitely interesting.

Answer (score 1):

In Bayesian land, the Beta distribution is the conjugate prior for the p parameter of the Binomial distribution.

Comment: Yes, but why is this the case?

Comment: It's quite mathy but here's an exhaustive answer https://towardsdatascience.com/beta-distribution-intuition-examples-and-derivation-cf00f4db57af

Answer (score 1):

Can't comment on other answers, so i have to create my own answer.

Posterior = C * Likelihood * Prior (C is a constant that makes Posterior integrated to 1)

Given a model that uses Binomial distribution for likelihood, and Beta distribution for Prior. The product of the two which generates the Posterior is also a Beta distribution. Since the Prior and Posterior are both Beta, and thus they are **conjugate distributions**. the Prior (a Beta) is called **conjugate prior** for the likelihood (a Binomial). For example, if you multiply a Beta with a Normal, the Posterior is no longer a Beta. In summary, Beta and Binomial are two distributions that are frequently used in Bayesian inference. Beta is Conjugate Prior of Binomial, but the two distributions are not a subset or superset of the other.

The key idea of Bayesian inference is we are treating the parameter p as a random variable that ranges from [0,1] which is contrary to frequentist inference approach where we are treating parameter p as fixed. If you look closely to the properties of Beta distribution, you will see its **Mean and Mode are solely determined by $\alpha$ and $\beta$ irrelevant to the parameter p** . This, coupled with its flexibility, is why Beta is usually used as a Prior.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an intuitive explanation that works for me:

$Binomial(n, p)$: 
When repeating a Bernoulli trial with $p$ probability $n$ times. The chance of exactly $k$ successes is:
$$Binomial_\mathit{pmf}(\pmb{k}, n, p) = {n\choose \pmb{k}} p^{\pmb{k}} (1-p)^{n-\pmb{k}}$$

$Beta(n, k)^*$: 
For a fixed $n$ and $k$, given probability $p$, calculate the probability, $p'$, of getting $k$ in the former experiment. Then multiply this $p'$ by $n+1$ to get $k'$, the most probable (interpolated) outcome if we have done the experiment with $p'$ (conceptually this is like the mode of $Binomial(n, p')$, only it allowes for non-integer values):

$$Beta_\mathit{pdf}(\pmb{p}, n, k) = \underbrace{(n+1) \overbrace{{n \choose k} \pmb{p}^k (1-\pmb{p})^{n-k}}^{p'=Binomial_\mathit{pmf}(k, n, \pmb{p})}}_{k' \approx mode(Binomial(n, p'))}$$

$\small{*}$ I'm using ${n \choose k}$ to emphasize the similarity with the $Binomial$. To get the actual $Beta$ function we need to replace $\cdot!$ with $\Gamma(\cdot+1)$, which interpolates the factorial for non-integer values.

**Note 1**: If $p$ is close to $k/n$, k′ is larger.

**Note 2**: If the parameter $n$ is larger we are more certain of the result (the concentration is higher).

**Note 3**: The get the common formulation for the $Beta(\alpha,\beta)$ function: 
$$k \to \alpha - 1$$
$$n \to \alpha + \beta- 2$$

**Note 4**: When replacing $\cdot!$ by $\Gamma(\cdot+1)$, $Beta(n, k)$ is actually defined for real-valued $n$ and $k$, with ranges $n > k - 1$ and $k > -1$. We can think of things like -0.3 successes out of -1.1 Bernoulli trials as interpolations from the integer $0 \le k \le n$ cases.

**Note 5**: $Beta(n=0, k=0) \equiv Uniform(0,1)$

**Note 6**: $\int_0^1(n+1){n\choose k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k} \,dp = 1$

Comment: $$(n+1){n\choose k} \pmb{p}^k (1-\pmb{p})^{n-k}$$how did you derive this?

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus I think Thomas Bayes derived it :).
See https://youtu.be/UZjlBQbV1KU?t=1074 (though his story is different)

Comment: This is supposed to be an intuitive explanation. Nothing more.
(I did replace 1 / BetaFunc with the (N+1) * binomial coefficient, is this the issue?)

Comment: *"The chance of at least one of the experiments having exactly k successes is"* I have difficulties to imagine how that equals $n+1$ time the probability of having exactly k success in a single run of the experiment. For instance when p=0.5, n=2 and k=1 then the probability equals 1.5 which makes no sense.

Comment: Yes, it's a PDF not a PMF. I'll rephrase.

Comment: So it is a likelihood and can be above 1. But still where does the multiplication with a factor n+1 come from. Why is it not something like $$1-\left(1- {n\choose k} \pmb{p}^k (1-\pmb{p})^{n-k}\right)^{n+1}$$ according to $$p(\text{at least one event in k trials}) = 1 -(1 - p(\text{one event in one trial}))^k$$

Comment: You're right. I edited my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107931/discussion-between-amit-portnoy-and-sextus-empiricus).

Comment: I see now. The first version made me confused. What you seem to be saying now is that the beta distribution is actually similar as the likelihood for $p$ with the binomial distribution. But why is that intuitive? It is not clear *why* it is like that. We can not do the same trick with other distributions so why does it work here while it doesn't for other cases? Is there some special property that makes it work, or is it just a coincidence? And why did you choose $n+1$? It is a parameter that normalizes the likelihood function, but is that the reason, or is there some more/other logic behind.

Comment: I am saying that it doesn't work for other cases, but I would actually have to check that out. Maybe there is some symmetry principle.

Comment: I don't know, but I think it may have something to do with the support size of the Binomial. In any case, I'm interested to know if there is any known symmetry principle. $1/(n+1)$ comes up analytically from integrating the likelihood of p.

Comment: Regarding "beta distribution is actually similar to the likelihood for p". I think this is how beta was viewed by Bayes. Start with the binomial likelihood for p, and find the constant that makes the integration works.

Comment: I believe that the beta distribution is foremost the conjugate prior distribution of the binomial distribution. The connection here is the relation $$cdfBeta(I, N-I+1, F) + cdfBinomial(N, F, I-1) = 1$$ which is a different thing then the relationship as conjugate prior.

Comment: I don't know the actual historical progress, but I've seen it presented as starting from the likelihood and finding a constant that makes it into a PDF. The fact that it happens to be the conjugate prior may have been just a nice coincidence (or intuition on Bayes part).

Comment: What I mean is that conjugate prior relates to this relationship between the pdf <-> likelihood (and related to that you refer to Bayes, which is not very clear and a bit handwaving). ---- The issue that is in this question is the relationship between **cumulative distribution functions**. You mention a relationship between the beta distribution and the binomial distribution, but that seems to me to be a *different* relationship. It is not clear what this has to do with the relationship between the CDF's.