# Summation of combinations up to $r-1$ terms

Tags: binomial-distribution, combinatorics, sum

I am trying to come up with a simplified expression for $$\sum_{k=r}^{n}\binom{n}{k}$$ 
Choosing $x=y=1$ in Binomial theorem, I have $$2^n = \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}$$ $$2^n = \sum_{k=0}^{r-1}\binom{n}{k} + \sum_{k=r}^{n}\binom{n}{k}$$ $$\sum_{k=r}^{n}\binom{n}{k} = 2^n - \sum_{k=0}^{r-1}\binom{n}{k}$$
Now, It looks like I need a simplified expression for $$\sum_{k=0}^{r-1}\binom{n}{k}$$
Am I stuck in a loop or I can get away? Any possible answer/tip would help me.

Comment: This is a multiple of the cumulative distribution for a Binomial$(n,1/2)$ variable.  That is given by an incomplete Beta function: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Because the [Binomial and Beta distributions are directly related,](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4659) compute that

$$\begin{aligned}
\sum_{k=r}^n \binom{n}{k} &= 2^n \sum_{k=r}^n \binom{n}{k} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^k\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-k}\\
&= \frac{2^n}{B(r, n-r+1)}\int_0^{1/2}  x^{r-1}(1-x)^{(n-r+1)-1}\,\mathrm{d}x.
\end{aligned}$$

The right hand side is $2^n$ times the cumulative distribution function of a Beta$(r, n-1+1)$ variable, evaluated at $p=1/2.$  Apart from the factor of $2^n,$ this is known as the [Incomplete Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function).  Because the denominator has a similar formula,

$$B(r, n-r+1) = \int_0^1  x^{r-1}(1-x)^{(n-r+1)-1}\,\mathrm{d}x,$$

the resulting expression is in a *closed form* (that is, its length--and the time needed for its evaluation--does not vary with $n$ or $r$ in a standard model of computing).