# What is the distribution of order statistic of Uniform distribution?

Tags: probability, distributions, order-statistics

I know from a theory that if $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ be iid from continuous Uniform(0,1), then k-th order statistic $X_{(k)}$ is Beta$(k,n-k+1)$.

Now, $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ be iid from continuous Uniform$(a,b)$, where $a=\mu-\sqrt{3}\sigma$ and $b=\mu+\sqrt{3}\sigma$. I would like to know that what is the distribution of $X_{(k)}$? Can I apply the theorem?

Comment: A Uniform (a,b) variable X can be written as a+(b-a)U, where U is Uniform (0,1). This should solve your problem.

Comment: @Xi'an Could you please explain for X=a+(b-a)U? Many thanks.

Comment: What I wrote is called an hint. You now have to work out the solution.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4659/relationship-between-binomial-and-beta-distributions/4684#4684.